# Scheme functions with lists

Tags: scheme

Let me begin with, I'm a beginner at scheme. Also this is based on HW so I'm not looking for an answer but an explanation of what's going on here. Here goes:

So I have a function that I need to implement which this much is given:

```
(define gen-hash-division-method
  (lambda (size)
    ...
  ))
```

Another function that I already implemented is defined as key and takes a word as a parameter and computes some value. It's correct so I won't post it but as an example `key('(w o r d)) => 130293`. Now all 'gen-hash-division-method' is supposed to do is just take the modulus of a key based on the parameter, in other words `h(k) = k modulus size`

The problem is, how am I supposed to compute that if k is not given as a parameter. This is how 'gen-hash-division-method' is meant to be used:

```
(define hash-1 (gen-hash-division-method 701))
```

701 I assume is the size parameter. And to test it, it looks like this:

```
(hash-1 '(h e l l o))
```

This is where I'm getting confused, I don't know what it's doing here. The word is given there but I don't understand how I'm supposed to call `key('(h e l l o))` to get k to implement `gen-hash-division-method(size) => k modulus size`

Comment: Hint: `hash-1` is a function (you know this from the example: `(hash-1 '(h e l l o))`.  `hash-1` is the result of `(gen-hash-division-method 701)`.  Therefore what must `gen-hash-division-method` return?

Comment: Then isn't `'(h e l l o)` a parameter for `hash-1`? But trying to follow you anyway, wouldn't it have to return part of the modulus function? So something like `(modulo ... size)` and somehow get `key('(h e l l o))` in there. Still confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see. `gen-hash-division-method` returns the modulus of a key based on the `size` parameter, but the characters that create the key will be passed later as another parameter, in other words:

```
(define gen-hash-division-method
  (lambda (size)
    (lambda (chars)
      (modulo (key chars) size))))
```

This is what's happening:

- `gen-hash-division-method` is a function that, given a size, returns *another function* specialized for calculating keys modulo size
- The returned function receives as parameter a list of characters
- Once a list of characters has been passed, the key is calculated using the `key` procedure, afterwards the modulo operation is performed, always using the same `size` passed when creating the function

What we just implemented is an example of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

> currying is the technique of transforming a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) in such a way that it can be called as a chain of functions, each with a single argument (partial application)

As you can see, it works as expected:

```
; hash-1 calculates hashes modulo 701
(define hash-1 (gen-hash-division-method 701)) 

; in particular, here we find the hash modulo 701 for '(h e l l o)
(hash-1 '(h e l l o))

; any other list of chars we pass will be hashed modulo 701
(hash-1 '(f o o))
```

Comment: wow this helped so much. the merits of scheme just shot through the roof in my eyes. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! hope you enjoy functional programming :)

Comment: One last question. When currying can you have something like `(define example (lambda (x) ...some code... (lambda (y) ...some more code...)))` and if that is possible does the first part execute when calling it like `(define test (example x))` and then the second part executes when calling `(test y)` ? This is more out of curiousity

Comment: That's right, the first lambda gets called the first time you call the procedure, and if you call the procedure that was returned (`test` in the example) then the second lambda will be executed